# Фильтрация данных по ключевому слову в Django ListView

Tags: python, django, listview

Прошу подсказать, как это сделать.
Есть страничка с таблицей условных изделий. Есть одна модель:

```py
class Robot(models.Model):
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='серия')
    model = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='модель')
    version = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='версия')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False, null=False, verbose_name='время создания')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.serial} {self.model} {self.version}'
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Столбец "Серия" я сделал так, что, кликая по названию, например, `kill` я попадаю на другую страничку, и на этой страничке показывается именно все записи с `kill`. Это происходит потому, что у меня во view в классе `ListSortRobotsView`, в методе `get_queryset` есть фильтрация именно по названию серии kill.

Так вот, как сделать, чтобы фильтрация происходила, еслия нажал на любое название серии, например, на `rex`, и появился список со всеми роботами у которых серия `rex`, или нажал на, условно, `QA`, и показались только роботы серии `QA`, или еще какое-нибудь название, которое может появится? А сейчас, на какую серию не нажимай, все равно появляется kill, потому что в фильтре прописано kill.

[image: таблица с изделиями]

```py
class ListRobotsView(ListView):
    model = Robot
    template_name = 'robots/index_robot.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_robots'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context


class ListSortRobotsView(ListView):

    model = Robot
    template_name = 'robots/all_serial_robots.html'
    context_object_name = 'serial_robots'

    def get_context_data(self, *, object_list=None, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Robot.objects.all().filter(serial='kill')`
```

Comment: Возможно я не правильно как то составил вопрос. Но хотел бы еще раз продублировать:

Comment: У вас что-то не так с изображениями (если посмотреть Markdown) поправьте пожалуйста.